# React-Warning-Keys in FlatList

Tags: react-native

I have some FlatList in my render but I'm getting Unique Key warning, I tried to use keyExtractor as well but it didn't work for me.
here is my code :

```
<FlatList
                    data={this.state.itemWaiting}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                      <MatchTurnList                    
                        username={item.home_user.username}
                        opponent={item.away_user.username}
                        matches={item.round_results} 
                        turnID={item.turn_id}                       
                        matchID={item.match_id}
                        userID={item.home_uid}
                        Rounds={item.round}
                        gameStatus={item.status}
                        onPress={() => console.log('hi')}                        
                      />
                    )}
                  />
```

and this is my warning :

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `MatchTurnList`. See ..... for more information.

and here is my matchTurnList component :

```
return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={0.9} style={styles.gameStatus}>
        <View style={{ flex: 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
          <Text style={[globalStyles.mediumFont, globalStyles.lightColor, globalStyles.acmeFont, { margin: normalize(1) }]}>{username}</Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            {a}   
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={[globalStyles.fontRifficFree, globalStyles.largFont, { color: '#ffbd00' }]}>VS</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Text style={[globalStyles.mediumFont, globalStyles.lightColor, globalStyles.acmeFont, { margin: normalize(1) }]}>{opponent}</Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            {b}
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
```

could you please help me to find where my mistake is?
Thanks.

Comment: Hey try and add key={index}(index as any unique value,userID should also work) to <TouchableOpacity>.May be that remove your warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use flatlist like this

```
render(){
return(
      <FlatList
         data={this.props.data} //<- your data array
         keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
         renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
)
}
```

then use **keyExtractor function** in your component like this

```
   _keyExtractor = (item, index) => String(item.yourID) //<- this id from your data.
```

and final **_renderItem function** like this

```
_renderItem = (item) => {
   <View>
      ...your code to render UI...
   </View>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have separate ID in my data array so I used index instead.
but it keeps getting me this warning

Comment: Is anything in data that uniquely define your records?

Comment: Thanks, I used another unique value for that. Also I had other for each loop in my component which needed to define a unique key for them. I did that and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try my code.
you need to add `key` props in render method

```
<FlatList
                    data={this.state.itemWaiting}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                      <MatchTurnList    
                        key={index}                
                        username={item.home_user.username}
                        opponent={item.away_user.username}
                        matches={item.round_results} 
                        turnID={item.turn_id}                       
                        matchID={item.match_id}
                        userID={item.home_uid}
                        Rounds={item.round}
                        gameStatus={item.status}
                        onPress={() => console.log('hi')}                        
                      />
                    )}
                  />
```

it will remove your warnings for uniques key.

Comment: there you need to add something like `      <TouchableOpacity key={this.props.key} onPress={onPress} activeOpacity={0.9} style={styles.gameStatus}>
</VIew>`

Comment: I tried your above solution bu it returned : 
Warning: MatchTurnList: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.

Comment: I also tried to change prop to "keyx={index}" and the add it to my component but No changes and still get the warning